# Spark accumulator used in transformation in ML lib

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have read that Spark accumulators should be used only in actions and not in transformations since Spark can only guarantee that the add method will be called once when it is in an action.

However, by looking at the implementation of Gaussian Mixture from the [Apache Spark repo](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/clustering/GaussianMixture.scala), for example, I can see in the `trainImpl` method that `logLikelihoodAccum` is used in a mapPartition transformation.

My question is: how bad is to do this? I would also want to use accumulator in a transformation and I want to evaluate the risks first.

Comment: As I see in the implementation, it uses the accumulator in a mapPartitions function to collect results for each partition. In a common spark ml transformer you don´t control that because it is a function that is executed for each row and to sync the accumulator for each row does not make sense(a priori)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have missed the point of Accumulators in Spark (Transformations & Actions).
Spark guarantees the usage of Accumulators only when an Action is invoked, not implemented.
Meaning, you should implement your Accumulator usage INSIDE a Transformation (that is the only way of using Acc, btw) and then invoke the RDD/DS chain (RDD/DS chain = T+T+...T+A) by using an Action (the Action is your catalyst).

"Spark can only guarantee that the add method will be called once when it is in an action" is misleading, especially the part "is in an action". You cannot enhance Spark Action, they are static. You can only enhance Transformations (some of them).

To answer your question: it is perfectly safe (optimization wise) to use Accumulators inside a Transformation (and then trigger it in order to invoke it).

Comment: What I have read so far was explicitly saying that accumulators should only be used in actions such as "foreach" and not in transformation because it can not guarantee that the "add" function will be called only once. Examples: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38422834/6631215 and https://blog.knoldus.com/is-using-accumulators-really-worth-apache-spark/.

Comment: And an official source: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.1/programming-guide.html#accumulators.

Comment: That's true. But you can set spark.speculation=false to guarantee that it does.